# LLVM why I get nothing in llc -print-after=stack-protector?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I have the same problem with [Run LLVM pass with opt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439705/run-llvm-pass-with-opt)

I followed the 

`llc -print-before=stack-protector hello.bc`

 but got nothing.

the `-print-before-all` works well, but there is no stack-protector pass in the output.

I used the `clang -emit-llvm -S -fstack-protector hello.c -o hello.bc` and the stack protector will be generated. So the pass worked, but why cannot be printed?

llvm version: 4.0

Comment: Don't really have an answer, but I think the issue is that the stack protector pass only gets added if it is turned on by something else. I.e. it is not available as a standalone option in llc. You need to add a switch to llc that causes it to be added. There are a number of options, but I don't have time to get to specifics right now.

Comment: @ZalmanStern That's a good advice, but I've checked the output of llc do have the stack protector. And the input of llc, i.e. hello.bc, has the tag of stack protector. So i think that's not the problem. Thank you all the same

Comment: It is possible the stack protector pass was already run on the .bc that you are feeding into llc. Have you checked that as well? If the pass is not showing up in a list of all passes that are run, that's a good sign that it is not being invoked in that run of llc.

Comment: @ZalmanStern I'm not sure which do you mean by run on the .bc. In the input i.e. the .bc  only contain a `ssp` tag for each function, but no IRs for he StackProtectors. After the llc, the IRs are generated and finally into assemble in .s. And I've tried both with and without `-fstack-protector` when i use clang. The llc doesn't work either.